# Prevent Multiple JFrame windows from opening

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Down towards the bottom of my code where I open up a new `JFrame` (`balanceFrame` or `valueFrame`), a new frame opens up with one of those frames when a user right clicks that menu option.

However, after closing the new `balanceFrame` or `valueFrame` that pops up, and you open up another `balance`/`valueFrame`, two open up. After you close those two and open another, three open up. Any idea on how to stop this? It seems like my programs remembering past values for the variable 'value' and opening up multiple windows.

```
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pressed");

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = source.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
                int column = source.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
                String value = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();

                if (! source.isRowSelected(row)) 
                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());

                menuItemBalanceSheet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            balanceFrame = new BalanceFrame("BalanceSheet", value);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        balanceFrame.setSize(1200, 600);
                        balanceFrame.setVisible(true);  
                        balanceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    }
                });

                menuItemCompanyValue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            valueFrame = new ValueFrame("Company Value", value);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        valueFrame.setSize(1200, 600);                      
                        valueFrame.setVisible(true);    
                        valueFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                        value.
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Why try-catch is used here, can you explain please??

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Not sure if relevant here, but see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @Rakibul islam Don't know eclipse told me too.

Comment: _Don't know eclipse told me too._ Well if you don't understand the Exception process, I would suggest that you learn basic Java, Swing is not something you use from the beginning. (And the ValueFrame constructor probably trow an exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding action listeners to your menu when you only want one.
Move this code to your initialization code:

```
 menuItemBalanceSheet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            balanceFrame = new BalanceFrame("BalanceSheet", value);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        balanceFrame.setSize(1200, 600);
                        balanceFrame.setVisible(true);  
                        balanceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    }
                });

                menuItemCompanyValue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            valueFrame = new ValueFrame("Company Value", value);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        valueFrame.setSize(1200, 600);                      
                        valueFrame.setVisible(true);    
                        valueFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                        value.
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you very much. I had to use a set and get method when I moved them for the value string.

Answer (score 0):

For this line one JFrame is created:

```
valueFrame = new ValueFrame("Company Value", value);
```

And again you are calling `setVisible(true)`. That's why second one is created:

```
valueFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Consider omitting one of them.

**Tips:**

Try performing `setSize()` and `setDefaultCloseOperation()` inside the main `ValueFrame` and `BalanceFrame` class. And in the upper where you have declared `JFrame balanceFrame;` and `JFrame valueFrame;`, try to do that `ValueFrame valueFrame;` and `BalanceFrame balanceFrame;`

Now in the down part of code, in `ActionListener` try this:

```
menuItemCompanyValue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            new ValueFrame("Company Value", value).setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }           
});
```

Comment: Without setting the frame to visible it doesn't open

Comment: Have you tried this. Well I've simplified my answer now. Try this and let me know if it solved.